# Apache Derby INSERTS are slow

Tags: java, database, derby

I am using Apache Derby to store a large number of rows in the order of 10s of Millions. Each time I initiate a batch insert, I will be inserting upto 2 Millions more rows into the table. 
The table has a UUID as its primary key and a single contraint to a UUID in one other table.
The insert takes hours !!! Why ?
I have created INDEXs on all the tables - but I have since removed this as I believe Derby automatically creates an INDEX for each table with a primary key.
I am using batch update with a prepared statement as shown (in very simple form below)

```
final PreparedStatement addStatement = connection.prepareStatement(...)
int entryCount = 0;
  for (final T entry : entries) {
    addStatement.addBatch();
    entryCount++;
    if (entryCount % 1000 == 0) {
    addStatement.executeBatch();
    addStatement.clearBatch();
    entryCount = 0;
    }
 addStatement.close();
```

Here are the results

```
05/01/12 12:42:48 Creating 2051469 HE Peaks in DB Table APP.ST_HE_PEAK_TABLE
05/01/12 12:44:18 Progress: Written (10%) 205146/2051469 entries to DB Table APP.ST_HE_PEAK_TABLE
05/01/12 12:46:51 Progress: Written (20%) 410292/2051469 entries to DB Table APP.ST_HE_PEAK_TABLE
05/01/12 12:50:46 Progress: Written (30%) 615438/2051469 entries to DB Table APP.ST_HE_PEAK_TABLE 05/01/12 12:56:46 Progress: Written (40%) 820584/2051469 entries to DB Table APP.ST_HE_PEAK_TABLE
05/01/12 13:04:29 Progress: Written (50%) 1025730/2051469 entries to DB Table APP.ST_HE_PEAK_TABLE
05/01/12 13:13:19 Progress: Written (60%) 1230876/2051469 entries to DB Table APP.ST_HE_PEAK_TABLE
05/01/12 13:22:54 Progress: Written (70%) 1436022/2051469 entries to DB Table APP.ST_HE_PEAK_TABLE
05/01/12 13:34:53 Progress: Written (80%) 1641168/2051469 entries to DB Table APP.ST_HE_PEAK_TABLE
05/01/12 13:47:02 Progress: Written (90%) 1846314/2051469 entries to DB Table APP.ST_HE_PEAK_TABLE
05/01/12 13:58:09 Completed: Written (100%) 2051469/2051469 entries to DB Table APP.ST_HE_PEAK_TABLE - Time Taken:01:15:21
```

As I insert more and more rows, the process gets slower and slower (probably becuase of the INDEX). The DB model I have at the moment serves my purposes well and I am reluctant to change it. 
Am I doing something wrong ? ... or expecting too much ?
Is there any way to improve the INSERT speed ?

---

**Edit**

I have already been tuned the DB using autocommit and others. I found that when INSERT millions of records - it does take an unreasonable amount time for my application. SELECT on this data is of course very fast.

Comment: You are aware you could keep the data persistent on disk with Derby, and load remote data as of the last record ID? _(Sorry for the obvious.)_

Answer (score 9):

Have you tried turning off autocommit mode?  From http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/dev/tuning/tuningderby.pdf:

Inserts can be painfully slow in autocommit mode because each commit involves an
update of the log on the disk for each INSERT statement. The commit will not return until
a physical disk write is executed. To speed things up:

- Run in autocommit false mode, execute a number of inserts in one transaction, and
  then explicitly issue a commit.
- If your application allows an initial load into the table, you can use the import
  procedures to insert data into a table. Derby will not log the individual inserts when
  loading into an empty table using these interfaces. See the Derby Reference
  Manual and the Derby Server and Administration Guide for more information on the
  import procedures.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have already been tuned the DB using autocommit and others. I found that when INSERT millions of records - it does take an unreasonable amount time for my application. SELECT on this data is of course very fast. I have had to restructure my DB to write a collection of objects using ProtocolBuffers works very well and is extremely fast - only problem is that I have to load the whole collection of objects whenever I want to use the data - but this is sufficicent for me.

Comment: @AndyTudor - can you explain: "I have had to restructure my DB to write a collection of objects using ProtocolBuffers works very well and is extremely fast - only problem is that I have to load the whole collection of objects whenever I want to use the data".  I am facing similar challenge and want to know if this is something I can do as well..